# Mocking a resource on Android instrumentation test

Tags: java, android, android-testing

I want to test the effects of a library call of my program with a real device. This call starts a service, that sends an HTTP request to a server whose URL that is hard-coded in the resources.

I want to verify that the request is sent correctly. So I set up a local HTTP server, but to be able to use it I have to change/override/mock the resource so it points to `http://127.0.0.1` instead.

I want to do "end-to-end" testing; in this case it's important that the service makes an actual network request, although locally.

I've tried to override the value by creating a string resource with the same name in `androidTest/res/values/strings.xml`, but that resource is only visible in the test package, not in the application package.

Using the `Instrumentation` class only allows me to obtain the `Context` reference, but there's no way to replace it (or the return value of `getResources()`) with a mock or something similar.

How can I change a resource value of an Application under test?

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple choices:

- Dependency injection
- Stubs/mocks
- SharedPreferences
- Scripts or gradle tasks

## Dependency injection

Use a library like RoboGuice or Dapper. Inject an object that handles making the API requests. Then, in your test setup, you can replace the injection modules with testing versions instead. That way your test code runs instead of the original; that code can pass in different strings (either hard-coded or from the test strings.xml) instead.

DI libraries can be expensive to setup: high learning curve and can be performance problems if not used correctly. Or even can introduce hard to debug problems if the scope/lifetime of the objects isn't configured correctly. If testing is the only reason to use DI, it might not be worth it to you if you're not comfortable with a DI container.

## Stubs/mocks

Wrap up your calls in something that implements a custom interface you write. Your main implementation then fills in the host URL and calls the API. Then, in tests, use a combination of stubs or mocks on that interface to replace the code that fills in the host URL part.

This is less of an integration test since the stubs or mocks will be replacing parts of the code. But is simpler than setting up a dependency injection framework.

## SharedPreferences

Use the Android SharedPreferences system. Have it default to a certain endpoint (production). But allow the app to be started on the testing device, then some dialog or settings to let you change the host URL. Run the tests again and now they point to a different API URL.

## Scripts or gradle tasks

Write some script or gradle task to modify the source before it is compiled in certain scenarios.

This can be fairly complicated and might even be too platform or system-dependent if not done right. Will probably be fairly brittle to changes in the system. Might introduce bugs if the wrong command is run to build the final packaged version and the wrong code goes out to the market.

## Personal opinion

Which do *I* recommend? If you and/or your team is familiar with a DI library like RoboGuice or Dapper, I recommend that option. It is the most formal, type-safe and strict solution. It also maintains more of the integrity of the stack to test the whole solution.

If you're not familiar with a good DI library, stubs/mocks and interface wrappers are a good fall back solution. They partly have to be used in the DI solution anyway, and you can write enough tests around them to cover a good majority of the cases you need to test (and are in control of). It is close enough to the DI solution that I would recommend this to everyone who doesn't use DI in the project already.

The SharedPreferences solution works great for switching between staging and production environments for QA and support. However, I wouldn't recommend it for automated tests since the app will most likely be reinstalled/reset so often during development, it would get annoying resetting that URL that often. Also, first runs of tests would probably fail; headless tests on a CI server would fail, etc. (You could default the URL to the localhost, but then you run the risk of accidentally release that default to production sometime.)

I don't recommend scripts or the hacked-up gradle tasks. Too brittle, less clear to other developers that come behind you, and more complicated then they're worth, IMO.

Comment: We're already using AndroidAnnotations that doesn't allow changing the production code AFAIK (it's working great for unit testing though), and using two DI frameworks in the same code may hinder maintainability. I would avoid SharedPreferences because this will make easier for malicious users to put a different URL in production. I've come up with another option that worked for me, that I will post as answer.

Comment: We hide the url endpoint dialog behind a simple 4 digit code. So to change it, users have to contact us.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Jon Adams's solutions, there's a further one:

## Override resource in build type

[By default, a library module is built in release mode](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Library-Publication) when it's used by another module. The debug mode is only used for testing (unit tests and instrumented tests). Therefore, using the resource overriding it's possible to change the resource value for the instrumentation tests for that library only, and use the original value in the library's users.

This has some caveats though:

- Instrumented/integration tests must stay on the library itself, not on the main application package;
- The same resource values have to be shared across all tests (unless using product flavors)